# Is there any reason I shouldn't use a FileReader?

Tags: java, performance, bufferedreader, filereader

Are there any downsides to using a FileReader in  Java?
I understand that unlike a BufferedReader, it doesn't use a buffer, but what sort of impact does it have on using a FileReader by itself?
Are there any times where a FileReader may be the ideal reader to use because of a greater speed and/or less memory usage compared to a BufferedReader?

I made a small benchmark test which showed FileReader to be slightly faster than the BufferedReader in almost every test, which there probably is a reason for (maybe because the BufferedReader was using a FileReader). So why does everyone seem to discourage using a FileReader if it appears to be faster?

Comment: "[...] if it appears to be faster?" This is very likely a consequence of constructing your benchmark a certain way.

Comment: Probably. So I guess I've created a benchmark which favors FileReaders over BufferedReaders. I'm trying to ask what caused the FileReader to be better in this case, and why does everyone seem to flat-out discourage it's use if it can be better?

Comment: The question "what caused the FileReader to be better in this case" cannot be answered unless you show us the code of "this case" :-)

Comment: I admit, that was badly worded. I'm wondering, in general, what causes a FileReader to be better than a BufferedReader, and therefore, when you should use it instead of the latter. It's just something I'm curious about and couldn't find anything online that didn't just say "BufferedReader is buffered so it's better".

Comment: Aside from questions of performance, you should avoid `FileReader` because it always uses the platform default charset, and relying on the platform default charset is basically always a bug waiting to happen. In new code you probably want to use static factory methods on the `java.nio.file.Files` class instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thank you. That actually makes a lot of sense. Does that mean if you were reading files that you knew used the default charset, it would be fine to just use a FileReader?

Comment: @JolonB: I would recommend always using APIs that are explicit about the `Charset` to use. That said, if this JEP is approved and implemented then it would probably be safe: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8187041